# Validating relationships invalids in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :value, type: String
  validates :value, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :cs
end

class B
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :a
  embedded_in :c
end

class C
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :bs
end
```

:

```
c = C.create #<C _id: 53c96d1f05dfd40943000001, >
c.valid? # true

a = A.create #<A _id: 53c96d8305dfd4b6e1000002, value: nil, c_ids: nil>
a.valid? # false

invalid_b = c.bs.create(a: a) #<B _id: 53c96dac05dfd4b6e1000004, a_id: "53c96d8305dfd4b6e1000002">

# Invalid object has created !!!!!
# a not been persisted but the c saved his id.

invalid_b.reload
invalid_b.a # nil
invalid_b.a_id # 53c96d8305dfd4b6e1000002
```

The "a" field is not valid yet "b" is being created.
How can I solve this problem?
So that the class "B" to validate the field before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you used

```
invalid_b = c.bs.create!(a: a)
```

instead of

```
invalid_b = c.bs.create(a: a)
```

the invalid record won't create and the `create!` will raise `Mongoid::Errors::Validations` exception

check http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html for reference